# How to specify directory to perform IO test in linux test project

Tags: linux-kernel

In Ltp, I want to perform the IO test in required directory. That directory would some required files. How can I specify the directory to ltp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one option -d. This provides to put the all temporary files in that directory.